# Can blockchain for all currency eliminate financial corruption in society?

Tags: society, government, politics, finances

Suppose I create a country where all currency is a cryptocurrency with tracked transactions. All income and outcome for a given country is registered in a block chain. All the public workers (specially all those working for the government) will get paid with the cryptocurrency associated to that blockchain and their accounts will be public. Taxes will be paid in that cryptocurrency.

Is financial corruption possible in such a country? If corruption is still possible, then is it possible if every country in the world used the same trackable blockchain?

Comment: Oh my sweet summer child, did you think corruption could only be financial?

Comment: Your intention is to make a cashless society? That's already sort of "a thing" - some businesses opt to go cashless and accept only payment by card. You just have to scale this to the entire country. But first you have to figure out how to deal with the very real problem cashless businesses result in - people can't pay by cash. Meaning that you're removing a chunk of the customers. Some people don't use cards for payment through choice or circumstances, so mandating this for everybody would be hard. Especially when you consider the homeless - how are they going to be doing payments?

Comment: No, and don't solve a small problem by creating several big ones

Comment: In what way is this about worldbuilding? Please review our [tour] and [help] so you can get a better idea what kinds of queries we accept here.

Comment: @elemtilas it could be, if it were about building a country using only blockchain. I don't think it is an entirely unreasonable fit for the site, even if I have sprained my eyes due to excessive rolling after merely reading the title.

Comment: It appears that informatics (= computer science, for Americans) is not your main interest. When thinking about a potential application of blockchain technology it is useful to replace the word "blockchain" with "mulitple copies of a giant Excel spreadsheet" and see if it still seems reasonable.

Comment: @StarfishPrime That is the point of asking, getting great answer from experts as you.

Comment: @VLAZ card and cryptocurrencies are totally different.

Comment: @Ivanovitch I'm focusing on the "cashless" part, not how you get there. Do you think it really matter to the homeless what they are unable to pay with when they are starving?

Comment: @Ivanovitch: The differences between credit / debit cards and "crypto" (note the scare quotes) currency are two. First, credit or debit card transactions are processed by a trusted third party, and *have to* be processed by a trusted third party; "crypto" currency transactions don't need a trusted third party. Second, and as a consequence, credit / debit card transactions are *very very* much faster, as in *several orders of magnitude* faster.

Comment: Hello, @Ivanovitch Welcome to WorldBuilding. Some people are flagging your question as "off topic" because it isn't about building an alternate world per se. I disagree, so I'm voting to leave it open. I'm going to edit your question a bit to make it more clearly on-topic. I hope you don't mind. My goal is to get the community a question they can answer and to get you better answers. :-)

Comment: Technology don't corrupt only human can.

Comment: @SRM thanks for keeping it open and for editing the question, now is more accurate.

Answer (score 8):

No, not even remotely.

A blockchain can certainly help with financial transparency.  But it itself won't prevent fraud.  For example, if the Dept of Agriculture gives a university $10 million to research something, the blockchain doesn't prove that money spent was actually worthwhile, or that it was the wisest thing to spend the money on.  A surprising amount of graft falls into that category of things.  Nor does it prevent 'soft' corruption, such as a company giving the son of a politician a high paying job to curry favor with the politician.  That is practically a way of life for the politically connected.

And of course the unintended but massive downside of the whole idea is the completely loss of all financial privacy.  Everyone will know what everyone else buys.  The implications of that are **very** dangerous for individual freedom.  Simply buying the wrong book or watching the wrong movie could lead to harassment.  Most certainly that will lead to people switching to some other means of exchange (such as a privacy oriented cryptocurrency).

Comment: Blockchain technology does not help with financial transactions; in fact, it makes them slower, potentially very much slower. What blockchain technology does is to allow financial transactions (or actually any kind of shared records) between two (or more) completely unrelated parties without the need of a trusted third party. That's all it does.

Comment: Plain-old bitcoin transactions can certainly be slow.  But there are other approaches by different cryptocurrencies that are no slower than existing credit card transactions.  I think what the OP was considering here is if the open nature of the bitcoin ledger would help prevent corruption, which I don't think it will.  At least, not by enough to justify the complete loss of financial privacy!

Comment: All kind of research involve 'wasting' money. and I am not talking about what everyone else buys, just how the people gets the money.

Comment: But yes, @AlexP you nailed right on the head what the purpose of it is - electronic transactions without an intermediary.

Comment: @GrandmasterB: Oh no, *any* kind of distributed blockchain tech is inherently very much slower than simply making *one* transaction in *one* database. Bitcoin's particular case is *ludicrously* slow -- tens of thousands of times slower than bank card transactions *at best*. (Non-distributed blockchain tech is a solution in search for a problem; it is reasonably fast, but it does nothing which a regular database cannot do.)